# csvsimple erros building csv table

Tags: tables, kile, csv, csvsimple

I want to use the csv package to insert tables into my document. 
I am importing csv by using the `\usepackage{csvsimple}` command.

Then, in the code, I use `\csvautotabular{Tables/test}` to create the tables of a csv file with the following content:

```
Year,Make,Model
1997,Ford,E350
2000,Mercury,Cougar
```

However, when I click the PDFLatex button in Kile to generate the pdf file, I get the following errors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this package still working? Is there an easier/better way to download my csv tables from Google docs into latex?

Comment: Works fine here, can you create a complete example? Another package that can create tables from text files is `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: What do the errors mean then? Can someone explain to me how I can fix them? I will look into that new package !

Comment: I think it usually means that there is a line break (`\\ ` or `\newline`) where it cannot occur. Again, can you create a complete example, a [minimal (non)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), if I do `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{data.csv}
\end{document}` it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a MWE, and testing around I finally found the problem: this error occurs when csvsimple cannot find the specified file. Which is quite dumb imo. If you ask me newline errors have nothing to do with FileNotFoundExceptions...

Comment: Yep, not ideal. There is a warning that the file is not found, but that should probably be an error instead. You could send an email to the package author reporting this (the email address is probably found in the manual).

Comment: Ok, I think this is the manual: http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf

If I am correct this is the e-mail: thomas.sturm@unibw.de

Trying doesn't hurt :D

Comment: Done. Just sent an e-mail to the creator with a link to this discussion !

Comment: I've put implementing a warning or error message for missing csv files on my todo list ...

Comment: The community appreciates :D